# Can I use Comparable to make TreeSet ordered?

Tags: java

There is a sentence from Oracle document:

> The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a
>   Comparator provided at set creation time, depending on which
>   constructor is used

I am wondering Comparable may be used for deciding the order of TreeSet, but I do not know how to certify my thought, so I do not know it is right or not. Can anyone give me the way to certify whether it is right or not? Any code or idea is appreciated.

Code is here for better explanation of my question.

```
final class Point implements Comparable<Point>{
    /***************** override compareTo*****************/
    public int compareTo(Point p){}
}
```

And I want to use a TreeSet to contain this kind object. To keep the order of the tree( because TreeSet use red black tree as its structure), I should override some method. The document said I should use `Comparator` as its underlying order. But I think 'Comparable' also works for keep my self-defined order in `TreeSet`

Comment: Yes, A class that implements `Comparable` would be used for "natural" ordering.

Comment: By definition, the "natural ordering" is the ordering defined by the Comparable interface implementation. To certify that, you could read the javadoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and click on the "natural ordering" link of the first sentence.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch  I know Comparable can be used for natural ordering but I want to know whether it can be used for manipulating the order of TreeSet.

Comment: @SHUYULYU what is unclear in "The elements are ordered using their natural ordering". You implement Comparable, that defines a natural ordering, and elements in the treeset are order according to this ordering, i.e. according to the ordering defined by your Comparable implementation.

Comment: Yes, if you implement Comparable, you are controlling the ordering - possibly different from the natural order.

Comment: @pczeus no. The order defined by the Comparable implementation **is** the natural ordering. If a class does not implement Comparable, it doesn't have any natural ordering.

Comment: What do you mean by `keep` it ordered? The objects order shouldn't change after they are added. It will break the Set. Also if an object is neither greater than or less than another object, it will be considered equal and not added to the set.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, the normal behavior for `TreeSet` is to sort by the natural ordering, so yes if you implement `Comparable` the default behavior should suffice.

```
// Sorted by "natural" ordering by default
Set<Integer> naturalSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();

// Different constructor that overrides this default behavior
// with an alternate Comparator
Set<Integer> nonNaturalSet = new TreeSet<Integer>(new NonNaturalComparator());
```